# Variable working outside of loop, but not inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

```
<% @sbp = Post.limit(4) %>
<div class="menu">
    <% @sbp.each do |sb| %>
        <a class="item" href="/introduction/integrations.html">
            <%= @sb.title %>
        </a>
    <% end %>
```

I have this code that I wrote with a basic loop of a limited query of Posts. This is in my main layout file in the header. `@sbp` works fine and can be called using `@sbp.first` both in and outside the query, but `@sb` is set to nill and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

My model for Posts:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :body, presence: true 
    validates_presence_of :slug

    def to_param
        slug
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing `sb` as an instance variable in the loop, but it isn't one.

Use the loop variable:

```
<% @sbp.each do |sb| %>
    <a class="item" href="/introduction/integrations.html">
        <%= sb.title %>
    </a>
```

- `@sbp` *is* an instance variable, presumably set in the controller.
- The object yielded by `each` is *not* an instance variable.